# Why date() works twice as fast if we set time zone from code?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, micro-optimization

Have you noticed that `date()` function works **2x faster** than usual if you set actual timezone inside your script before any `date()` call? I'm very curious about this.

Look at this simple piece of code:

```
<?php

  $start = microtime(true);
  for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  echo (microtime(true) - $start);

?>
```

It just calls `date()` function using `for` loop 100,000 times. The result I’ve got is always around **1.6 seconds** (Windows, PHP 5.3.5) but…

If I set same time zone again adding one absurd line before start:

```
date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());
```

I get a time below **800ms**; ~2x faster (same server).

I was looking around to find any reasonable explanation for this behavior but did not have any success. From my angle, this additional line is useless but PHP doesn’t agree with me.

I have tried this test on two linux servers (different PHP versions) and got different resulting times but in proportion **~6:1**.

Note: **date.timezone** property in **php.ini** has been properly set (Europe/Paris).

I was searching for related questions here and did not find anything similar. I've also checked manual for [date_default_time_zone() function @ php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and found that I'm not only one who noticed this, but still can't understand why that happens?

Anyone?

Comment: Wow.  Behavior duplicated, 5.3.3 on CentOS 5.x (though at ~0.65 and 0.31 seconds respectively).  If this still happens in 5.3.6 (I'll be able to test later this week if nobody else gets to it), I think it might be worth filing a bug.

Comment: @Charles - yes... on linux, php 5.3.2 its 4.16 and 0.7 (without timezone it's always ~4s, with timezone it's 0.7 and less).

Comment: sorry it was PHP 5.2.13, on 5.3.2 it's 2:1.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Update for PHP 5.4:

As documented in the description of [`date_default_timezone_get`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php), starting from PHP 5.4.0 the algorithm to guess the timezone from system information [has been removed from the code](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/date/php_date.c#guess_timezone) (contrast with the PHP 5.3 source) so this behavior no longer exists.

Running the timing test on my dev server to see it in action, I got:

- PHP 5.3.11: ~720ms
- PHP 5.4.3: ~470ms

### Original answer:

I 've just looked into PHP source. Specifically, all relevant code is in [`/ext/date/php_date.c`](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/date/php_date.c).

I started with the assumption that if you don't provide a timezone for `date`, `date_default_timezone_get` is called to get one. [Here's that function](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/date/php_date.c#4035):

```
PHP_FUNCTION(date_default_timezone_get)
{
    timelib_tzinfo *default_tz;

    default_tz = get_timezone_info(TSRMLS_C);
    RETVAL_STRING(default_tz->name, 1);
}
```

OK, so what does `get_timezone_info` look like? [This](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/date/php_date.c#get_timezone_info):

```
PHPAPI timelib_tzinfo *get_timezone_info(TSRMLS_D)
{
    char *tz;
    timelib_tzinfo *tzi;

    tz = guess_timezone(DATE_TIMEZONEDB TSRMLS_CC);
    tzi = php_date_parse_tzfile(tz, DATE_TIMEZONEDB TSRMLS_CC);
    if (! tzi) {
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_ERROR, "Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen!");
    }
    return tzi;
}
```

What about `guess_timezone`? [Here](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/date/php_date.c#guess_timezone) it is:

```
static char* guess_timezone(const timelib_tzdb *tzdb TSRMLS_DC)
{
    char *env;

    /* Checking configure timezone */
    if (DATEG(timezone) && (strlen(DATEG(timezone)) > 0)) {
        return DATEG(timezone);
    }
    /* Check environment variable */
    env = getenv("TZ");
    if (env && *env && timelib_timezone_id_is_valid(env, tzdb)) {
        return env;
    }
    /* Check config setting for default timezone */
    /*  ..... code omitted ....... */
#if HAVE_TM_ZONE
    /* Try to guess timezone from system information */
    /*  ..... code omitted ....... */
#endif
#ifdef PHP_WIN32
    /*  ..... code omitted ....... */
#elif defined(NETWARE)
    /*  ..... code omitted ....... */
#endif
    /* Fallback to UTC */
    php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_WARNING, DATE_TZ_ERRMSG "We had to select 'UTC' because your platform doesn't provide functionality for the guessing algorithm");
    return "UTC";
}
```

**OK, so how does that interact with `date_default_timezone_set`?** Let's look at [that function](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/date/php_date.c#4012):

```
PHP_FUNCTION(date_default_timezone_set)
{
    char *zone;
    int   zone_len;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &zone, &zone_len) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    if (!timelib_timezone_id_is_valid(zone, DATE_TIMEZONEDB)) {
        php_error_docref(NULL TSRMLS_CC, E_NOTICE, "Timezone ID '%s' is invalid", zone);
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }
    if (DATEG(timezone)) {
        efree(DATEG(timezone));
        DATEG(timezone) = NULL;
    }
    DATEG(timezone) = estrndup(zone, zone_len);
    RETURN_TRUE;
}
```

Long story short: if you call `date_default_timezone_set` once, then `guess_timezone` takes the fast path of reading from the `timezone` variable (the very first conditional is satisfied, and it returns immediately). Otherwise it takes some time to work out the default timezone, which is not cached (I guess for simplicity), and if you do that in a loop the delay starts to show.

Comment: Nice work. So it wasn't a PHP level error triggering after all. I'm deleting mine.

Comment: and because no body runs the code 100k times, they don't bother to cache guessed timezone.

Comment: Wow, thanx Jon, it's really nice work... It seems that I was not looking in the right direction. I'm completely satisfied with this answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @nerkn - yes I know, it's ridiculous. But that was my way to get the most appropriate result.

Comment: I figured it would be something like that.  Thanks for putting the work in necessary to confirm it.

Comment: @Jon, Interesting... I didn't notice that... thanks for update. How it works now? Guess it uses some var to make TZ value accessible from date functions w/out guessing (which we can change manually from code).

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: There are two variables `timezone` and `default_timezone` that can influence the result; if none are set the system defaults to UTC.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine it has to determine the timezone for itself each time it's called unless explicitly specified, which adds to the function runtime.

But really, does it matter?  How many scripts are you likely to make that call date() 100,000 times per run?

Comment: But why would it have to determine the time zone for itself when a default one is set in php.ini?

Comment: This question is not related with speed up, rather internals of php