# Help implementing past date validation

Tags: php, javascript, validation, datetime

I need to implement something that checks if a given date is greater than today. If for example, I input a date of April 19, 2011 while today is April 15, 2011, there should be some validator/pop up error. How do I implement this?

I have my system date (today's date) working fine through php. I just don't know how to create a validation/error message when the user inputs a higher date than today.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code explaining where you are so far? It would help to know the formats those dates are coming back as.

Answer (score 1):

**It can be done with PHP (on server side) and with JavaScript (on client side, in browser).**

Here is an example of how to do it on **JavaScript**:

```
var currentTime = new Date()
    month = currentTime.getMonth(),
    day = currentTime.getDate(),
    year = currentTime.getFullYear(),
    today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

var users_day = '2011-04-19';

if (users_day > today) {
     alert ("Entered day is greater than today");
}
 else {
     alert ("Today is greater than entered day");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example (in PHP)

```
date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get()); // not necessary here

$today = strtotime('2011-04-15');
$users_day = strtotime('2011-04-19');

if ($users_day > $today) {
  echo "Error";
  }
else {
  echo "OK";
  }
```

Example above outputs

```
Error
```

...because `April 19, 2011` (user's input) is greater than `April 15th, 2011` (today).

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());` what is that supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Jacob, to re-set same timezone from code and increase speed of date(), strtotime(), etc. functions execution time. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556789/why-date-works-twice-as-fast-if-we-set-time-zone-from-code). That's unnecessary here but I'm puting that line always when I use any of date/time functions in PHP (actually at the beginning of every my PHP script).

Comment: Noice. Thanks Wh1T3h4Ck5 and jacob :D