# date.timezone issue

Tags: php

Hey all - I am getting an error on my CMS site that reads as this:

> Warning: strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'UTC' for 'UTC/0.0/no DST' instead in /var/www/html/test-site/libs/utils.php on line 97.

So I went into that folder and placed this before any of the functions:

```
date.timezone = "America/New_York";
```

However, when i try to reload my page the entire site is down.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks

Comment: What you did was place a php.ini directive into your PHP code, and those directives are themselves not valid PHP code, so you introduced a syntax error.

Comment: Agree with @Marc + when you put this line into `php.ini` don't use `;` at the and of line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either choose to ignore the warning (which in most cases is fine), or explicitly set the time zone using [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set).

Writing `date.timezone = "America/New_York";` isn't proper PHP, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

aha!  I found that :

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Did the trick

Comment: No no no, this works but it's not the best method to do this, you should change the data.timezone within your `php.ini` file, and then restart apache or whatever server your using !

Comment: @Robert - I disagree. Even you set `default.timezone` in `php.ini`, PHP will try to 'guess' timezone before execution of every date/time function. Yes, it's good to set `date.timezone` in `php.ini`, but setting it again from php code is recommended. Even `date_default_timezone_set(date_default_timezone_get());` makes sense. Look at [this question and accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556789/why-date-works-twice-as-fast-if-we-set-time-zone-from-code). So I agree with @Sapp, this is the best way to avoid PHP 'guessing' timezone setting. @Sepp +1

Comment: sorry, i ment `date.timezone` in previous comment.