# Fastest way to convert a UNIX timestamp

Tags: php, performance

I've written a little script to count the number of accesses from a logfile.

```
   for($j=0; $j < $max; $j++) 
   {
   $tempyear = date('Y', $timestamp[$j]);
   $tempday = date('z', $timestamp[$j]);
   for($i=$fromdate; $i <= $todate; $i++)
      {
      if ($tempyear === $yeartoday) {
      if ($tempday == $i) {$dayaccesses[$i] = $dayaccesses[$i]+1;}}
      }
   }
```

I've noticed that the execution speed is very slow due to the conversion of the UNIX timestamp.

For example, if I would save the year and the the day of year in plain text the script would execute much, much faster...

> For 12.000 entries [in seconds (not as previously stated microseconds)] 
>   Plain text date: 0,14  
>   Timestamp conversion: 0,58

So is there any (hopefully simple) way to speed the timestamp conversion up?

Comment: One man's *"slow"* is another man's *"so fast you won't ever notice it unless you try to"*...

Comment: Anyway, as far as microoptimizations go, you could use `gmdate()` which skips the timezone conversion. Or if you are really obsessed with this then calculate an approx. date yourself `$t_year = 1970 + time() / (60*60*24*30*12)` and so on...

Comment: Despite this being micro-optimization, @mario's comment made me remember a `date()` related performance question that indeed showed some potential for a speed-up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556789/ you could try setting the time zone in your code as shown there.

Answer (score 5):

The difference you show, 0.445 microseconds, is *0.000445 seconds.*

This is not worth any serious consideration. More time has already been wasted by this question, than will ever be saved by an optimization. :)

Comment: actually, "microseconds" was a typo - I meant seconds... so 0,4 seconds - still not much, I know - but noticable...

Comment: @Nyoman 0,4 *seconds* is different - in that case, try the link in the comment above. But do you really have an everyday situation where you need to do 12,000 conversions in one request? Maybe you need to look into caching to speed this up?

Answer (score 1):

Trust the words from a [very smart man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth):

> We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil
>
> "Premature optimization" is a phrase used to describe a situation where a programmer lets performance considerations affect the design of a piece of code. This can result in a design that is not as clean as it could have been or code that is incorrect, because the code is complicated by the optimization and the programmer is distracted by optimizing.

Quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

So, as Pekka already said, don't optimize when there's really no good reason to optimize.